# ASP.NET MVC: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 Application.
My view get a List from my controller.
I want to select these list with lambda expression but I get the following error:

Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

```
List<project.Models.LAYER> layers = new List<project.Models.LAYER>();
layers = @Model.layers.Select(x => x.KONT == "EUROPE");
```

@Model.layers is a List

NOW I TRIED THAT: BUT THE SAME ERROR:

```
@{
  List<project.Models.LAYER> layers = Model.layers.Where(x => x.KNOT == "EUROPE").ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code compiles? You don't need the @ sign here which would switch from HTML to a C# expression (and back at the end of the expresion). But your extract of the code is pure C# (no need to switch). Furthermore, why do you assign a new empty list to `layers` and the immediately assign it another value?

Comment: What sort of list is `Model.layers`? Is it a `List<project.Models.LAYER>`? Probably not as the error message indicates there is a dynamic type involved somewhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you're doing this in your view, which violates the principles of separation of concerns.  But this is how you would do it.

```
@
{
   var layers = Model.layers.Where(x => x.KONT == "EUROPE").ToList();
}

@foreach(var layer in layers)
{
  .....
}
```

### A Better Way

What you should do however is create a method on your Model "GetLayersForLocation"  Then your code would look like this:

**In Your Model Class**

```
public IEnumerable<Layer> GetLayersForLocation(string location)
{
    return this.layers.Where(x => x.Knot == location);
}
```

**In Your View Code**

```
@foreach(var layer in Model.GetLayersForLocation("EUROPE"))
{
  .....
}
```

The reason this is better is you can now unit test your code, before you wouldn't be able to because it's just part of your view, but now you can run automated tests to ensure that getting the proper layers is working.

Answer (score 8):

For others, I've notice I get this error in Views when I **do not have a strongly typed view**, **such as if a single character accidentally gets typed before the "@model type"** line (and thus the model type declaration is now no longer being made.)

```
 @model SomeModel
```

Answer (score 1):

1. layers is a List, Model.layers.Select will return an `IEnumerable.`
2. If you only want to return layer whose `KONT == ‘EUROPE'`, you should use like following

   ```
   layers = @Model.layers.Where(x => x.KNOT == "EUROPE").ToList();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: 
I tried that now:

 @{
   List<poettinger.Models.LAYER> layers = new List<project.Models.LAYER>();
   layers = @Model.layers.Where(x => x.KNOT == "EUROPE").ToList();
}

But there is still the same error.