# Looping inside razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have  field name "GroupTitle" assigned to each Control. I want to loop through each element of Control assigned to particular group.

```
public class Groups
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string GroupTitle { get; set; }

}

public class Controls
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //Id
    public string Name { get; set; } //name of control/element
    public string ControlType { get; set; }  // checkbox, radio button, textbox, time, date
    public string Caption { get; set; } //caption/title/label        
    public string Content { get; set; } //in case of checkbox        
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; } //is mandatory to select or enter its value.                 
    public string GroupTitle { get; set; } // there will be title at the top of controls if grouped together                

    //public List<SelectListItem> SelectOptions { get; set; } //select/dropdown options e.g. Pakistan, Uk for country dropdown        

}
```

Below is my code . I am not sure how to access Model variable inside nested loop. This gives me error. Also it gives me error that Where clause does not exists.

```
@foreach (var groups in Model.Groups)
{                                                    
    foreach (var row in Model.Controls.Where("GroupTitle ==",  @groups.GroupTitle;))
    {   

    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain to us, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please see my modified post.

Comment: I think you probaly mean `foreach(var row in Model.Controls.Where(r => r.GroupTitle == groups.GroupTitle));`

Comment: yes but this gives me error can not use lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove this:

```
@foreach (var groups in Model.Groups)
{                                                    
    foreach (var row in Model.Controls.ToList().Where(x => x.GroupTitle == groups.GroupTitle))
    {   

    }
}
```

I think [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17084396/19046) probably also applies to your case.

Comment: i receive error Lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Comment: This is probably because Controls is IQueryable. I updated the answer to convert it to a List.

Comment: to test your suggested link i used this statment @{
    var layers = from p in Model.Controls where p.GroupTitle = "GroupTitle" select p;
}
but it gives me error Query expressions over source type 'dynamic' or with a join sequence of type 'dynamic' are not allowed